# How to add a Subview using [self.view addSubview: myView] where myView is subclass of UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, subclass, addsubview

In my Project, I have a customised @interface `GraphView: UIView`. Hence `GraphView` is a subclass of `UIView` and is meant to show a graph.

Then, I create a new View Controller called `Summary` using a NIB. In the Interface builder, I just add a `UIToolbar` at the bottom of the View.

In the implementation of `Summary`, in the `viewDidLoad` method, I have the following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  GraphView *myGraph = [[GraphView alloc]init];
  [self.view addSubview:myGraph]; //this does not work
}
```

But I am unable to get this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to set the frame of `myGraph` before you add it as a subview to `self`.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 0.0, 0.0);
GraphView *myGraph = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[self.view addSubview:myGraph];
```